# Dynamic views for different screen sizes

Tags: android

I am working on a project in which many views are generated dynamically and apps will be running on different screen size. So is there any way to take care of the screen size in the code while views are generating dynamically and apps is running on different devices. Thanx in advance

Comment: what do you mean "to take care"?
in general there's no difference between views that you create dynamically and views that you create in layout-file.
using layouts is just easier way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be really specific then use:

`DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);`

Then you can specify in IF statements what screen pixels you want to change your layout for, in certain ways.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's possible that.

GO to AndroidManifiest.xml file - > Manifiest Tab - > Add Screen supports .
and you can also seen that in last AndroidManifiest.xml Tab like this .

<  supports-screens

```
    android:xlargeScreens="true" 

    android:resizeable="true" 

    android:normalScreens="true" 

    android:anyDensity="true" 

    android:smallScreens="true" 

    android:largeScreens="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
txtView.setLayoutParams(p);

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

use WRAP_CONTENT or FILL_PARENT not fix no for hieght and width

use dp and sp as unit

Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities

Provide different layouts for different screen sizes